# Normalize a character's position that is at bottom

Tags: css, text, unicode

I'm using the [Unicode Character "HORIZONTAL ELLIPSIS"](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2026/index.htm):

```
…
```

Its' "natural" positioned is at bottom, as is the cases with the period or comma.

I intend to use it as an icon and not for textual context, so I wonder if it's possible to "normalize" it's vertical position to center (like the position of a dash)?

Comment: With a relative position you can move it upwards (or using absolute or transform) ... the best would likely be to use some other dots, e.g. bullets `•••` instead of ellipsis `…`

Comment: Thanks a lot, that solves my root case in the easiest way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U can use `line-height`:

```css
span {
  vertical-align: top;
}
span:nth-child(1) {
  line-height: 1.2;
}
span:nth-child(2) {
  line-height: 1;
}
span:nth-child(3) {
  line-height: .5;
}
span:nth-child(4) {
  line-height: 0;
}
```

```html
<span>…</span>
<span>…</span>
<span>…</span>
<span>…</span>
```